# How to Unload DLL from memory in C?

Tags: c, winapi, memory, dll, loadlibrary

How to unload DLL from memory. I used FreeLibrary but it is still loaded

```
HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary("path.dll");
f_funci func = (f_funci)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "method");
int x = func();
FreeLibrary(hGetProcIDDLL);
```

I used `UnmapViewOfFile` and `FreeLibraryAndExitThread` but it still in memory too

Comment: What does `FreeLibrary()` return? (you might also want to check the return value of `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()`).

Comment: @Danny_ds  FreeLibrary() return true.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'still in memory'?

Comment: may be you can try to call [`GetLastError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683152(v=vs.85).aspx) function, to see what it returns.

Comment: @H.DJEMAI return unsigned int with value 0

Comment: Library handles are reference counted.  If the library has been loaded more than once (either implicitly or explicitly) it will need to be freed the corresponding number of times.

Comment: Why do you think it's still in memory?

Comment: The two functions  `LoadLibrary` and `FreeLibrary` works very well, see my answer.

Answer (score 24):

In this example, I'll show a short test where we can see that the two functions `LoadLibrary` and `FreeLibrary` works very well.

I'll use [`Process explorer`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) to show if the DLL is loaded or not in the current process address space.

So I have created a very simple dll named test3.dll

And here is a simple program to use it:

```
// A simple program that uses LoadLibrary and 
// Access test3.dll. 
// Then Unload test3.dll 
#include <windows.h> 
#include <iostream> 

typedef int (__cdecl *MYPROC)(LPWSTR); 

int main( void ) 
{ 
   HINSTANCE hinstLib; 
   BOOL fFreeResult; 

   // Get a handle to the DLL module.
   hinstLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("test3.dll"));    //1: load the DLL

   // If the handle is valid, unload the DLL
   if (hinstLib != NULL) 
   {  
       fFreeResult = FreeLibrary(hinstLib);      //2: unload the DLL
   } 

   return 0;
}
```

**First step:**

When we execute this statement:

```
hinstLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("test3.dll"));
```

Here is the result:

[image]

We can see clearly that test3.dll is loaded in the address space of the process `useDLL.exe`

**Second step:**

When executing `fFreeResult = FreeLibrary(hinstLib);` statement, here is the result:

[image]

As we see, the DLL is no longer loaded in the address space of the process useDLL.exe

**The two functions `LoadLibrary` and `FreeLibrary` works great.**

You can look at [this tutorial to see how to use `process explorer`](https://kb.froglogic.com/display/KB/Getting+a+list+of+DLLs+currently+loaded+in+a+process) to show the loaded DLL in a given process.

Comment: @user7435875 If that answer was helpful you should've accepted it. (As this is the only answer and IMHO valuable, I would recommend it.)